# User Unable to Log Into Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, user-management

I have the latest RC release of Windows 7. Added a Homegroup and all is fine.

I am not on a domain but a Workgroup (by default).  My computer name is `QuadHomePC` and user name is Paul.

I set up my user to automatically log into windows and specified the password.

However, after a restart I get to the Windows Login screen and my username or password is rejected.

I attempted logging in using the following usernames followed by my normal password:

```
Paul
QuadHomePC\Paul
paul
quadhomepc\paul (to ensure it is not case sesitive)
```

All Failed.  However I have noticed a 2nd user called "`HomeGroupUser$`" has added and maybe have something to do with me setting up a homegroup account?

I am wondering if I can reset the password somehow or if there is a backdoor into Windows 7.

Any advice would be grateful.

Comment: Can you make it more clear exactly what you are typing into the username field, it should be "computername\username", and what error message do you get(not that windows should give feedback if it is a user error or password one, but maybe it does?

Comment: I tried "computername\user" which is QuadHomePC\paul but my username or password is rejected by windows.  Its the same password I always use for my home network so I know it is correct.  I will try http://home.eunet.no/pnordahl/ntpasswd/ later to see if I can remove the password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following software:

http://home.eunet.no/pnordahl/ntpasswd/

And found out that my username was not actually "paul" but "quadhomepc" which is odd and the reason why it wouldnt let me on.  There was also a 2nd user account called "HomeGroupUser$".

So using quadhomepc as my username worked?  I checked my user account and it is infact "paul" which is very strange!  Maybe this is a Windows 7 RC issue to be resolved!

Thanks for all your help, its much appreciated.

Paul

Answer (score 0):

When you setup Windows 7, you needed to enter a reminder (a clue/secret question) for the password. Try checking that. Try entering the password while having CAPS Lock ON. There is a possibility that when you entered the password for the first time, CAPS was ON.

On a computer on a Workgroup, there is not need to use "Computername\User" or "Workgroup\User" while trying to login. Both make no sense.

In the worse case scenario, rebuild. Try to remember the password you used this time :-)

Comment: I know the password, its the one I always use for all my home computers.  Its just that Windows Login is rejecting my username or password?  When I enabled the password yesterday and set it up to login in automatically it asked for my password (and 2nd time to confirm) without any problems.  I think there is somethign funny because a new user account is added called "HomeGroupUser$".

Comment: I tried all variations of computername\username with and without the computername but to no avail.  Everything was ok until I played with the HomeGroup which as I mentioned as appeared to added a new user

Comment: Where did you get that copy of Windows 7 RC?

Comment: Microsoft website - its totally legit and I never download from anywhere other than the official source and ALWAYS avoid torrents and p2p downloading!

Comment: I have been running it fine since the RC release on both a media pc and it has been fine this past week until this morning?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a long shot, but you might try Paul@QuadHomePC for your username.